# Using Leaps or glmnet on Large Datasets

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R and its features but I have heard good things about `leaps` and `glmnet`.  Is there a way to use the model selection packages `glmnet` or `leaps` on sets of data with a large number of explanatory variables?  I would like to fit a model using them but I have about 100 different variables and the examples I've found seem to suggest I would have to input each variable manually.  I am basically looking for a method that lets me choose a column to be the response variable and then takes in all other columns for model selection or takes in the first column as the response and all others as explanatory variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is actually built into the syntax of the R language.

What you do is just prepare a dataset with your response and explanatory variables, then type:

`glmnet(y ~ ., data = data)`

adding whatever other options you like. The dot operator tells it to use all other columns as explanatory variables.

You can also do things like this, to use all variables bar one:

```
result <- glmnet(y ~ . - x3, data = data)
```

Technically, . means all variables not already mentioned in the formula. For example

```
result <- glmnet(y ~ x1 * x2 + ., data = data)
```

There are other things you could do as well, such as using a loop to assign variable names programmatically to a list, but this should be the easiest solution.

Comment: Very cool, I didn't realize that was possible.  Would you be able to explain or link to an explanation of how to use a loop to assign variable names for future reference?

Comment: Sure. So, you could do something like `cols <- colnames(df)` or `cols = list()
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  cols[i] <- colnames(df[i])  then you can use that list of columnames in any way you like, such as to paste(cols, sep=",")`  to get a comma separated list of variables or directly reference columns. If your response variable is in there make sure to remove it, such as `cols[[1]]<- NULL` if it were the first element.

Comment: Thank you, I think I see what you mean.